# Significance test for the difference of two correlation coefficients

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation

Okay, I have two different data sets, A and B, both of which correspond to a third data set, C.  I have run least-squares regression on both A with C and B with C.  The correlation coefficient of A with C is 72.9%, compared to 66.5% for B with C.  How do I know or how do I test that that 6.5% difference is significant?

Comment: If I type <significance of difference of two related correlations> into Google, the first link is: http://www.quantitativeskills.com/sisa/statistics/corrhlp.htm 

Which provides a link to a web page that does the calculation for you.

The references at the bottom of the page provide the formulas that are used (and I imagine that some of the other links from that search will give you the formulas too.)

Answer (score 3):

Correlation coefficients aren't expressed in percentages, except maybe when squared to represent a shared percentage of variance. It also sounds as though you're referring to three variables within one dataset. If so, you're looking to test the difference of dependent correlations. [Jeromy Anglim's blog has some useful links on this](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/09/significance-tests-on-correlations.html). Steiger's *Z*-test is described in [Cal Garbin's "Bivariate Correlation Comparisons (PDF)](http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/statpage/biv_corr_comp_eg.pdf), which I'll paraphrase as a four-step calculation:
$$rm^2=\frac{\big(r_{AC}^2+r_{BC}^2\big)}{2}\\f=\frac{1-r_{AB}}{2(1-rm^2)}\\h=\frac{1-(f\cdot rm^2)}{1-rm^2}\\Z_\text{difference}=(Z_{AC}-Z_{BC})\cdot\frac{\sqrt{N-3}}{\sqrt{2(1-r_{AB})h}}$$
You can find the *p* value of *Z*<sub>difference</sub> very easily – it's from the *z* distribution!

If all this is a pain (it is), you can use the `paired.r` function in the `psych` package in [r](/questions/tagged/r) as described on [another of Jeromy's blog posts](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-r-to-test-for-significance-test.html) (linked in the previous). All you'll need are the three bivariate correlations and the total number of cases (trios of observations for each variable).

Comment: Additionally, if your data sets are not normally distributed, then a bootstrap method may be more robust than a correction based simply on the correlation between A and B and the number of points. See [Wilcox 2009](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610910903289151).